# Unintended Reallocation of Multi Dimensional Vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a function two sum up, *in a different way*, values of a Matrix.

The different way; with transposing the matrix.

```
int matrixElementsSum(vector<vector<int>> matrix) {
    int sum = 0;
    vector<vector<int>> tmatrix;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix[i].size(); i++)
    {
        vector<int> row;
        
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.size(); j++)
        {
            row.push_back(matrix[j][i]);
        }
        cout << "Controlling the size" ;
        cout << "   " << matrix[i].size() << endl;
        tmatrix.push_back(row);
    } 

    for(int i = 0; i < tmatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < tmatrix[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if(tmatrix[i][j] == 0) break;
            sum += tmatrix[i][j];
        }
            
    }
    return sum;
}
```

input:

> [[5, 10, 15]
> ,[20, 25, 30]]

output:

> Controlling the size   3
> Controlling the size   3
> Controlling the size   8
> 105

And my question is: when the size of my vector is changed from 3 to 8?
And also how?

Comment: If your compiler / standard library (which one are you using?) has a debug mode, please enable it, it would tell you that you are accessing a vector element beyond the end.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
```

and

```
for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
```

?